# Which is better package Design?

Tags: android

I am working on a shopping cart application for Android. While creating package design, I can think of 2 options

Design 1. Divide packages based on role like

```
com.shoppingcart.activity //all activity classes

com.shoppingcart.utility //all utility classes

com.shoppingcart.database //all database handlers
```

etc

or

Design 2. Divide based on component

```
com.shoppingcart.login

com.shoppingcart.searchproduct

com.shoppingcart.order
```

Which of the 2 designs will be better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1 is better, because java package name is a design time concept not runtime.